# Changing the reading order of Rubygem sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have created a private gem that I have hosted myself.  Everything was going well up until someone has created a gem with the same name on rubygems.org. Since rubygems.org has a highest precedence over my gem server url. I am not able to install my gem anymore. I tried to remove the rubygems source:

```
$ sudo gem source -r http://rubygems.org
```

and reinstall it so it comes after in the gem source list, but it does not work.

Is there a way to change the lookup order of the gem source?

Note that I don't want to rename my gem.

Comment: I’m not sure if this will work, but you could try manually editing your `.gemrc` file and change the order of the sources in there.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the `specific_install` gem:

`gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l <git-url>`

Another way is to explicitly state the gem server like so:

`gem install mygem -s http://gems.example.com`

The best option, in my opinion, is to use Bundler. In your Gemfile add:

`gem 'mygem', :git => 'git://git.example.com/myrepo.git'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried the: `gem install mygem -s http://gems.example.com` and it did't work. I got it to work afterward, but I don't know why. Might be a cache issue.

Comment: I order to install my gem i had to `gem source -r http://rubygems.org` then `gem install mygem -s http://gems.example.com`. And then adding back http://rubygems.org. I am wondering if there is a better way to clean the cache.

Comment: if I don't do the `gem source -r http://rubygems.org` the rubygem version gets installed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you can't have an empty gem cache. If you delete the http://rubygems.org cache manually with `gem source -r http://rubygems.org`, and there are no other sources defined, it automatically gets repopulated. Kind of an annoying misfeature, really.

What did the trick for me was adding my source (an internal server) and then readding rubygems manually.

```
$ gem source add http://internal-server/
$ gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

 http://rubygems.org/
 http://internal-server/
$ gem source -r http://rubygems.org/
$ gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://internal-server/
$ gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
$ gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://internal-server/
http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have the issue anymore since I am not working on the project that I was on. If I ever encounter the issue I will try your solution and give you some feedback.