# Using Chef with Private Gem Server

Tags: chef-infra

I am currently using Chef behind a firewall and run a private gem server. I would like to be able to use community cookbooks from the Supermarket without modification but the issue I am having is that I cannot figure out how to configure the Chef Client to pull gems from my private gem server and not rubygems.org when community cookbooks install gems via the chef_gem resource.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have searched high and low but could not find an answer.

Comment: are you using a gemfile? else you might be able to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112381/changing-the-reading-order-of-rubygem-sources  on changing the gem sources to your own server first?

Comment: I guess my question is around how do i even configure the gem sources for Chef?  Do I do in it client.rb?  Do I do it globally on my system?

Comment: Perhaps having a recipe that comes first and copies a file into ~root   Based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475382/possible-to-change-gem-sources-for-chef-client

Comment: I will give that a try @Doon.